# What is the lowest frquency possible?

Tags: cpufreq, frequency

What is the minimum possible frequency of a CPU (in my case I have the  Intel® Core™ i7-8750H CPU @ 2.20GHz × 12)

Comment: do `grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/cpuinfo_min_freq`. likely 800 MHz. If you want lower, there is a way, but it involves writing to MSRs directly.

Comment: thank you very much! would you recommend setting a lower frequency, or is this 800MHz minimum freq okay?

Comment: You have not told us what your application or problem is, so I can not comment. Processor energy consumption should be low enough at 800 MHz, if that is the objective.

Comment: Yes, my objective is to reduce energy consumption as much as possible to increase battery life.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer uses primitive commands. Someone else might add another answer about tlp or other higher level utilities.

It isn't always the case that minimum CPU frequency means longest battery life. Sometimes completing a task faster, at higher CPU frequency, results in so much extra time in deep, low power, idle states, that energy is actually saved. The term for this is "race to idle". The highly non-linear portion of the performance/power curve is in the "turbo" region. Therefore often it is enough to simply disable turbo.

By default, your computer should be using the intel_pstate CPU frequency scaling driver and the powersave governor. Check via, and for example:

```
doug@s18:~$ grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy*/scaling_driver
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy0/scaling_driver:intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy1/scaling_driver:intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy2/scaling_driver:intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy3/scaling_driver:intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy4/scaling_driver:intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy5/scaling_driver:intel_pstate
doug@s18:~$ grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy*/scaling_governor
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy0/scaling_governor:performance
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy1/scaling_governor:performance
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy2/scaling_governor:performance
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy3/scaling_governor:performance
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy4/scaling_governor:performance
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy5/scaling_governor:performance
```

Oh, well let's fix that:

```
doug@s18:~$ echo powersave | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy*/scaling_governor
powersave
doug@s18:~$ grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy*/scaling_governor
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy0/scaling_governor:powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy1/scaling_governor:powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy2/scaling_governor:powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy3/scaling_governor:powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy4/scaling_governor:powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy5/scaling_governor:powersave
```

Now, if turbo is not disabled in the BIOS, it will default to enabled, so disable it:

```
grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo
doug@s18:~$ grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo
0
doug@s18:~$ echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo
1
doug@s18:~$ grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo
1
```

By default HWP (HardWare Pstate) should be enabled on your computer, so you can also tell it to prefer power saving over performance:

```
doug@s18:~$ grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy*/energy_performance*
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy0/energy_performance_available_preferences:default performance balance_performance balance_power power
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy0/energy_performance_preference:balance_performance
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy1/energy_performance_available_preferences:default performance balance_performance balance_power power
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy1/energy_performance_preference:balance_performance
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy2/energy_performance_available_preferences:default performance balance_performance balance_power power
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy2/energy_performance_preference:balance_performance
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy3/energy_performance_available_preferences:default performance balance_performance balance_power power
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy3/energy_performance_preference:balance_performance
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy4/energy_performance_available_preferences:default performance balance_performance balance_power power
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy4/energy_performance_preference:balance_performance
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy5/energy_performance_available_preferences:default performance balance_performance balance_power power
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy5/energy_performance_preference:balance_performance
```

and:

```
doug@s18:~$ echo power | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy*/energy_performance_preference
power
doug@s18:~$ grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy*/energy_performance_preference
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy0/energy_performance_preference:power
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy1/energy_performance_preference:power
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy2/energy_performance_preference:power
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy3/energy_performance_preference:power
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy4/energy_performance_preference:power
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy5/energy_performance_preference:power
```

Now. if you still want to reduce the maximum CPU frequency, you can do it via two methods:

```
doug@s18:~$ grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/*perf_pct
/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/max_perf_pct:100
/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/min_perf_pct:17
doug@s18:~$ echo 17 | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/max_perf_pct
17
```

Or:

```
doug@s18:~$ grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy*/scaling_m??_freq
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy0/scaling_max_freq:3700000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy0/scaling_min_freq:800000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy1/scaling_max_freq:3700000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy1/scaling_min_freq:800000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy2/scaling_max_freq:3700000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy2/scaling_min_freq:800000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy3/scaling_max_freq:3700000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy3/scaling_min_freq:800000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy4/scaling_max_freq:3700000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy4/scaling_min_freq:800000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy5/scaling_max_freq:3700000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy5/scaling_min_freq:800000
doug@s18:~$ echo 800000 | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy*/scaling_max_freq
800000
doug@s18:~$ grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy*/scaling_max_freq
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy0/scaling_max_freq:800000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy1/scaling_max_freq:800000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy2/scaling_max_freq:800000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy3/scaling_max_freq:800000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy4/scaling_max_freq:800000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy5/scaling_max_freq:800000
```

Now, let's use turbostat to observe powers under some of these conditions, using prime95 torture test, the most brutal CPU stress program I know of:

```
$ sudo ./turbostat --Summary --quiet --show Busy%,Bzy_MHz,IRQ,PkgWatt,PkgTmp,RAMWatt --interval 6
Busy%   Bzy_MHz IRQ     PkgTmp  PkgWatt RAMWatt
0.28    800     320     32      2.07    1.89
2.17    800     1136    33      2.10    1.89
99.36   4088    36118   67      105.53  1.96 <<< level 2 power throttle alrady active
99.32   4131    36077   62      108.98  1.96
100.12  4071    36076   64      99.94   1.96 <<< level 1 power throttle, 100 watts.
100.12  4070    36074   65      99.92   1.96
100.12  4069    36078   65      99.94   1.96
100.11  4067    36106   65      99.92   1.96
100.11  4066    36077   65      99.91   1.96
100.11  4065    36091   65      99.93   1.96
100.11  4063    36177   65      99.92   1.93
100.10  4061    36072   65      99.93   1.90
100.10  4059    36083   65      99.92   1.90
100.14  3966    36254   58      93.05   1.90
100.26  3700    36109   58      72.93   1.90 <<< turbo disabled
100.26  3700    36073   58      72.94   1.90
100.26  3700    36087   59      73.19   1.89
100.26  3369    36298   49      60.96   1.89
100.26  2800    36081   49      39.78   1.89 <<< start reducing max CPU freq more.
100.26  2800    36076   48      39.82   1.89
100.26  2800    36202   48      39.76   1.89
100.26  2371    36128   45      30.00   1.89
100.26  2300    36168   45      28.30   1.89
100.26  2300    36262   45      28.20   1.90
100.26  1976    36122   43      22.39   1.90
100.26  1900    36072   43      20.99   1.90
100.26  1900    36071   43      20.95   1.90
100.26  1900    36205   43      20.96   1.90
100.26  1486    36122   40      14.81   1.90
100.26  1400    36100   40      13.55   1.90
100.26  1400    36073   40      13.54   1.90
100.26  1400    36205   40      13.60   1.90
100.26  1082    36116   39      9.83    1.90
100.26  1000    36076   39      8.89    1.90
100.26  1000    36195   38      8.88    1.90
100.26  878     36131   38      7.84    1.89
100.26  800     36075   38      7.19    1.89 <<< until lowest possible
100.26  800     36070   38      7.22    1.89
100.26  800     36086   38      7.26    1.89
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! This is really helpful, and I now understand some stuff that had me confused. Thanks!

Comment: You could accept my answer. Doing so indicates to future readers/searchers that it might actually be useful.